# Confusion regarding an equality on product set

Tags: real-analysis

We have $\{ X_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A} $ collection of nonempty sets. $X = \prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha} $ and $\pi_{\alpha} : X \to X_{\alpha }$ is coordinate maps. Given the collection

$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}( E_{\alpha} ) : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} , \alpha \in A \} $$

where $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $X_{\alpha}$. The product sigma algebra on $X$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{F} $.

Why does it follow that

$$ \prod_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha} ) $$

?? Ive been trying to understand this for hours, and I cant get it.

Comment: Suppose that $A = \{1, \dots, n\}$, then $\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_{\alpha} = X_1\times\dots\times X_n$. Note that $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_{\alpha}) = X_1\times\dots\times X_{\alpha - 1}\times E_{\alpha}\times X_{\alpha + 1}\times\dots\times X_n$. Can you see why the stated equality holds in this case? The general case is analogous.

Comment: I don't understand how the identity on your second line holds. Is this definition of preimage ? I thought $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}( E_{\alpha} ) = \{ y = \pi_{\alpha}(x) : x \in E_{\alpha} \} $

Comment: $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha) = \{  (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A} \in \prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha \mid \pi_\alpha((x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}) \in E_\alpha \}.$

Comment: Why $x_{\alpha} $? This is my confusion.

Comment: The set in your last comment is actually the direct image $\pi_\alpha \left(\prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha\right)$.

Comment: Another way to write the preimage in Ivo Terek's comment is $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}) = \{x \in X \mid \pi_{\alpha}(x) \in E_{\alpha}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just about set theory, and has nothing to do with sigma algebras and such.

Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}\in \prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha$. So: $$\pi_\alpha((x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}) = x_\alpha \in E_\alpha \implies (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A} \in \pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha).$$Since $\alpha \in A$ is arbitrary, this gives $\prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha \subset \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)$.

On the other hand, take $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A} \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)$. So given any $\alpha \in A$, we have that: $$x_\alpha = \pi_\alpha((x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}) \in E_\alpha \implies (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}\in \prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha,$$by the definition of  the inverse images. This gives $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)\subset \prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha$. Done.

Comment: I don't understand why on third line $\pi_{\alpha} (x_{\alpha} ) = x_{\alpha}$

Comment: By definition of the projection. There's a difference between $x_\alpha$ and $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$: the first is an element of $E_\alpha$, the second is an element of $\prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha$. It pays well not to be sloppy with the notation here..

Comment: I understand now. I was confused with the notation. On line $6$, we have by definition that $x_{\alpha} \in E_{\alpha} $ for all $\alpha \in A $. How does this imply that $(x_{\alpha}) \in \prod_{\alpha} E_{\alpha} $ ?

Comment: *Again*, by **definition** of the product. Because $x_\alpha \in E_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in A$ gives $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A} \in \prod_{\alpha \in A}E_\alpha$.

Comment: I'll swap letters, maybe it helps. $$(y_\beta)_{\beta \in B} \in \prod_{\beta \in B}F_\beta \stackrel{\rm def}{\iff} \left(y_\beta \in F_\beta,\quad\forall\,\beta \in B\right).$$